# what does "DependsOn": [] means in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am using a AWS supplied template which uses "DependsOn": [] in a nested stack call.
I know dependson can have a list dependencies but have never come across this.

```
BucketsStack": {
        "DependsOn": [],
        "Properties": {
            "Parameters": {
                "CreateDemonstration": {
                    "Ref": "CreateDemonstration"
                },
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57437050/aws-lambda-and-iam-error-on-deploy-the-role-defined-for-the-function-cannot-be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove it as it is an empty array so it is useless  .

Indeed `DependsOn` affects the order of resources creation.

Below is from the [official documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html).

> With the DependsOn attribute you can specify that the creation of a
>   specific resource follows another. When you add a DependsOn attribute
>   to a resource, that resource is created only after the creation of the
>   resource specified in the DependsOn attribute.